# Terraform - Hashicorp DNS Provider error - bad authentication

Tags: dns, terraform

I am trying to use the Hashicorp DNS Provider to create dns records in our Microsoft AD DNS environment.

I have worked through various errors such the krb5 config, username but now stuck on this error below when I run a terraform apply:

module.ad_dns_a_record.dns_a_record_set.ad_a_record[0]: Creating... ╷ │ Error: Error updating DNS record: dns: bad authentication │  │   with module.ad_dns_a_record.dns_a_record_set.ad_a_record[0], │   on ../main.tf line 2, in resource "dns_a_record_set" "ad_a_record": │    2: resource "dns_a_record_set" "ad_a_record" {

Everything looks correct, we are using a custom krb5 config file.
I have tried from a linux and a windows domain joined machine.

Anyone had the same error and can help with what the issue could be ?

Example of the tf confg:

```
provider "dns" {
  update {
    server = var.dns_server # Using the hostname is important in order for an SPN to match
    gssapi {
      realm    = "AD.TEST.COM"
      username = "svc_xxxxx"
      password = "xxxxxxx"
    }
  }
}
```

Setup to use as a module. Running below code to test creating a record

```
module "ad_dns_a_record" {
  source      = "../"
  dns_zone    = "inf.test."
  name        = "test"
  dns_records = ["192.168.177.177"]
  ttl         = "300"
  record_type = "A"
}
```

Create a dns record.

Added module code.

```
resource "dns_a_record_set" "ad_a_record" {
  count     = var.record_type == "A" ? 1 : 0
  name      = var.name
  zone      = var.dns_zone
  addresses = var.dns_records
  ttl       = var.ttl
}

resource "dns_cname_record" "ad_cname" {
  count = var.record_type == "CNAME" ? 1 : 0
  name  = var.name
  zone  = var.dns_zone
  cname = var.dns_records
  ttl   = var.ttl
}
```

KRB5 Config.

```
# Configuration snippets may be placed in this directory as well
includedir /etc/krb5.conf.d/

[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
# dns_lookup_realm = false
# ticket_lifetime = 24h
# renew_lifetime = 7d
# forwardable = true
# rdns = false
# pkinit_anchors = FILE:/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
 default_realm = AD.TEST.COM
# default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

[realms]
AD.TEST.COM = {
 kdc = xxxx.ad.test.com
 kdc = xxxx01.ad.test.com
 }

[domain_realm]
 .ad.test.com = AD.TEST.COM
 ad.test.com = AD.TEST.COM
```

Comment: And what is the value given to the `dns_server` variable in your example?

Comment: its the fqdn of a dns server. eg "xxxx.ad.test.com"

Comment: And what is in `module.ad_dns_a_record.dns_a_record_set.ad_a_record[0]`? Can you add that to the question as well?

Comment: Added the module code and custom krb5 config.

Comment: Although its not mentioned anywhere do I need to set a spn for my AD service account that I have specified in the code ?

Comment: I've resolved the issue. For anyone else getting the issue it was due to me testing on a subdomain. For it to work I needed to append the subdomain to the name field and not the zone field.